# how to retrieve profile pics of all fans of my facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I need to retrieve the profile pics of my FB page fans to create a collage. I knew that FB doesn't allow us this via FQL or via their API. Is there any workaround to retrieve the fan pics.

Ref: http://www.thefacesoffacebook.com/

thanks
SM

Comment: "knew that FB doesn't allow us this via FQL or via their API" - correct, which means there's likely no way to do it here without somehow scraping the www.facebook.com site

Answer (score 0):

Actually a very easy solution is to retrieve the list of friends witht the $facebook->api('me/friends', 'GET') request, then just do a foreach to the results and add the friend id in an array or db whatever you want and in the img tag where you want to parse the image justo put this src **http://graph.facebook.com/{friend_id}/picture** this automaticly will redirect to the user profile pic.

The path will end with a _q.jpg if you want to do normal thumb size, replace the q with an n, and you will have the thumb of a friend.

I know this is not the best way but is a way, hope this help you

**The best way :)**

```
$facebook->api('{friend_id}/picture', 'GET',  array(
'redirect' => false,
'width' => XXX,
'height' => XXX,
'type' => 'square' 
));
```

And you're done, this will return an array with the indexs: url, width, height and is_silhouette (the last one is for know if the user has the default facebook thumb)